# One-to-many query with subtoals and limits

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

Requirements: Select customers with 5 or more invoices totaling more than $3000 with transactions from Sept 2011 to current date.

DBMS: MySQL 5.6

Tables:

- customers: customerID (...)
- invoice: customerID,invoice_no,order_date,order_total (...)

I wrote several MySQL queries. The one that comes "closest" to working appears below. The problem with the results is twofold:

1. It looks at the total of all invoices per custopmer, not just those within the date range.
2. It pulls in some (but not all) records that are outside of the date range.

Here is the query:

```
#Customers with 5 or more invoices Totaling more than $3000 From Sept 2011 to current
SELECT distinct c2.customerID,c2.firstname,c2.lastname,c2.company,c2.address,c2.address2,c2.city,c2.state,c2.country,c2.phone,c2.email,SUM(c1.order_total)
FROM
    customers c2 LEFT JOIN invoice c1 
    ON c2.customerID = c1.customerID
         AND ((date(c1.order_date)) between '2011-09-01'  and date(now())) 


GROUP BY
    c1.customerID
HAVING

COUNT(c1.invoice_no)>=7 and sum(c1.order_total) >=3000
```

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Thanks.

Comment: Smells like homework...

Comment: Blow your nose. Your sense of smell is off. We just released a software upgrade and want to contact a select group of people to make them a special offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select c.*, SUM(i.order_total) total, COUNT(*) order_count
FROM customers c
JOIN invoice i ON c.customerID = i.customerID
WHERE i.order_date >= '2011-09-01'
GROUP BY c.customerID
HAVING order_count >= 5 and total > 3000
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Barmar. Checked a couple of random records. One had a total of 2990 but the invoice count was correct. One had a total of 3300 but had only 3 invoices.

Comment: I don't see how that could be, unless you changed `AND` to `OR`.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: OK. Fixed it. I needed to add and i.invoice_status like "%approved%" to handle the various approved stati. Your solution works perfectly now. Thanks so much!